# Why is this private constructor inaccessible to its friend

Tags: c++, constructor, g++, private, friend

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class B {
private:
  class A;
  friend void f ( A Aobj );
  B ( int i ) {}
};

class A{
};


void f ( A Aobj ) {
  B Bobj ( 1 );
}

int main() {      
}
```

g++ produces the following error:

```
$ g++ a.cpp
a.cpp: In function ‘void f(A)’:
a.cpp:10: error: ‘B::B(int)’ is private
a.cpp:18: error: within this context
```

The error goes off if any of the following changes are made:
1. Remove the "int i" from the constructor of B.
2. Change the data type of f from A to anything else: eg void f ( int Aobj ).
3. Define class A prior to B and remove the forward declaration of A.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the friend function takes a `B::A`, where the function later on in the file takes a `A`. Move the forward declaration of `class A` out of `B`.

Comment: +1, same as above. Your f() declaration is a different function from the f() you mention as a friend in declaration of B().

Comment: OK, but can you now explain the observed compilation results when you remove the `int` parameter from the constructor? Why does it compile in that case?

Comment: @ondav: Perhaps that is related to the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)?

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the constructor of B - the function B (int i){} as a private method. You want to make this public, like so:

```
class B {
private:
  class A;
  friend void f ( A Aobj );
public:
  B ( int i ) {}
};
```

**EDITED

If you want to keep the constructor private, that shouldn't be an issue. Looking at it again, I realize the error lies with the forward declaration of the class A. You've declared A in the class definition of B, and then try to use it in the function header for f. The problem is that you haven't defined A fully, so you cannot reference the object yet - the compiler doesn't know how much memory A takes up, so the function cannot be defined. To fix this, you either need to fully define class A before any reference to it, or switch f to take a pointer to A (i.e. `void f (A* Aobj)`). Pointers are a fixed size, so they can be used even if A hasn't been defined fully yet.

Comment: f is a friend of B. So f should be able to access B's private methods as well.

Comment: Also please note that the in the original code, if the parameter ("int i") to B's constructor is removed, it compiles fine.

Comment: I've edited to better answer, I think. I'm pretty sure what happens when you remove the parameter is that the compiler assumes you are using the implicit constructor, which is public.

Comment: @rkevingibson I do not think so. When you explicitly define the private constructor, the compiler cannot override it to public. Or can it? I must delve into the standard ...